# Alsa snd_mixer_open() 'open mode'

Tags: c, alsa, mixer

In the [documentation](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___mixer.html#ga240cfebce7d68f22875d76e99cf19394) for snd_mixer_open, the description for the second parameter `int mode` is: "open mode". But I can't find any further information about which symbolic values to use in the same module. After some searching, I found that in the snd_ctl/control module, there are symbolic values like SND_CTL_NONBLOCK and SND_CTL_ASYNC, and also SND_CTL_READONLY. But I have still no indication which ones are ok to use in the `snd_mixer_open` function! And as these are prefixed with 'SND_CTL' I have the impression they are only meant for functions of the snd_ctl module.

(What I'm generally trying to achieve, is to be able to read the volume level of the master channel of the default sound card.)

Comment: there is other function prototype https://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/native/reference/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.audio/topic/libs/snd_mixer_open.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483929/set-mixer-as-default-alsa-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source in [alsa-lib/src/mixer.c:68](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-lib.git;a=blob;f=src/mixer/mixer.c;h=3a79c8e91efb0f6c67c0ba365b54eb6f72679d69;hb=HEAD#l68) the "mode" argument is flagged as unused:

```
int snd_mixer_open(snd_mixer_t **mixerp, int mode ATTRIBUTE_UNUSED)
```

and the source of the function bears that out. So it looks like it's safe to use any int there (I'd personally just go with 0).

Comment: In the future, some mode bits might be used.